# Python Error. Trying to convert number into list and pull out first digit

Tags: python, string, list, typeerror

So this:

```
for n in range (500):  
    lst = [int(i) for i in str(n)]  
    first_n = int(n[0])  
    list = lst  
    print list     
    print first_n
```

Is giving me the TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '**getitem**'.
But if I change the 3rd line from n into i then this:

```
for n in range (500):  
    lst = [int(i) for i in str(n)]  
    first_n = int(i[0])  
    list = lst  
    print list   
    print first_n
```

Gives me the list and the last number on that list. I need the first number not the last.
It gives me the first if instead I replace `n in range (500):` with `n = raw input()`

```
n = raw_input()   
lst = [int(i) for i in str(n)]   
first_n = int(n[0])   
list = lst  
print list   
print first_n
```

But this is single number and need to have run thousands of numbers. (As you can see I change the i on the 3rd line back into n)

Please can you help?

Comment: shouldn't first_n = int(n[0]) be first_n = int(lst[0])?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue lies with the raw_input. In python 2, it returns a string, not an integer. What you need is input(), which just returns an integer:

```
n = input()   
lst = [int(i) for i in str(n)]   
first_n = int(lst[0]) #also, need lst here, not n, as it is now an integer
list = lst  
print list   
print first_n
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably an easier solution here is to instead convert it to a string:

```
>>> str(123)[0]    # Convert to string and take 1st character
'1'
```

If you need it as a number, you can `int` it back. This feels inefficient, but you're trying to solve a problem strongly related to the written representation of a number, so strings feel like the appropriate solution. You can however use solutions related to taking the place value. If you are looking for the number of hundreds in the above, for example, you could `% 100`. This requires a little more work to make general, though.